# Cannot run bash script Cisco Anyconnect. "Sorry, you need user privileges to run this script." When executing as root

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, 22.04, cisco

For work i need to install Cisco Anyconnect and i can't get it to install due to a rights issue.  I have everything set up, i think correctly. I'm following [this instruction](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/smb/routers/cisco-rv-series-small-business-routers/Kmgmt-785-AnyConnect-Linux-Ubuntu.html).

After step 8 (executing the bash script), i keep on getting the error message "Sorry, you need super user privileges to run this script".

The script should have access to /opt/

### What i've done to fix this:

- I've followed the instructions and of course used sudo
- Run script as root user (su -c etc)
- Edited permissions of the /opt/ folder chmod 755
- Changed owner of script and /opt/ to my user account(and reverted, no fix)
- Created a new folder /opt2/ and edited the script to use that folder

Anyone can help me fix this?

---

Edit: i'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

---

Script rights

- file: vpn_install.sh
- owner: username
- group: root
- user::rwx
- group::rwx
- other::rwx

/opt/ rights

- file: opt/
- owner: root
- group: root
- user::rwx
- group::rwx
- other::rwx

---

Terminal output:

```
username@user-NUC10i7FNK:~/Documents/anyconnect/anyconnect-linux64-4.10.07073-predeploy-k9/anyconnect-linux64-4.10.07073/vpn$ sudo ./vpn_install.sh

Installing Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client...
Sorry, you need super user privileges to run this script.
Exiting now.
```

---

Edit:

- ID my user: 1000
- ID root: 0

Script opened in text editor

```
# Make sure we are root
if [ `id | sed -e 's/(.*//'` != "uid=0" ]; then
  echo "Sorry, you need super user privileges to run this script."
  exitInstallation 1
```

Terminal sudo id

```
UID=0(root) GID=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

---

Additional info: I changed the script to run as UID 1000

New error message:

```
mv: can not move '/tmp/anyconnect-linux64-4.10.07073-core-vpn-webdeploy-k9-11321613022024.log' to'/opt/cisco/anyconnect/./anyconnect-linux64-4.10.07073-core-vpn-webdeploy-k9-11321613022024.log': access denied
```

Comment: The instructions said `sudo` not `su -c` so you could try that. Please also [edit] with the full terminal output that includes the error

Comment: Done @DanielT thanks

Comment: I neither have an account nor found the exact version, so I'm basing this off of `anyconnect-linux64-4.10.05095-predeploy-k9.tar.gz `. You can open the script in a text editor and use CTRL+F for the "Sorry, you need super" part. I see ```[ `id | sed -e 's/(.*//'` != "uid=0" ]```. Can you [edit] with `sudo id` ?

Comment: You have the right version i think. I edited, thanks.

Comment: Please run the `sudo id` command

Comment: Done, all 0, UID, GID and groups

Comment: I don't know what shell you're using (try `sudo bash ./vpn_install.sh` instead) that is giving the "UID" as uppercase, but Ubuntu is supposed to give a lowercase "uid" output. If that still doesn't work and you're confident that you're using `sudo`, you can just delete the `if [...] fi` block in the script as a workaround then run it.

Comment: sudo bash did not work, however, removing the whole statement did. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I will move my comments to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a strange problem with the `/usr/bin/id` command in your `/bin/sh` shell. Perhaps you installed something different that produces different uppercase "UID" output that is not compatible with scripts that expect the default lowercase "uid" Ubuntu version. Let's just work around the problem by removing the check:

1. Open the `vpn_install.sh` script in a text editor
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for "Sorry, you need super user privileges"
3. Select the enclosing `if [...] fi` block.
4. Delete or comment it out
5. Make sure you run the script with `sudo` to avoid your second `mv` privileges error because there will be nothing left to warn you

Comment: This looks like it might be a coreutils locale thing - in particular, the po files for hr (Croatian), nl (Dutch) and es (Esperanto) have uppercase `"UID=%s"`. However I don't understand why the script doesn't use something more robust like `[ "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ]` .

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for the insight. I don't understand the script either. Instead of `id`, it could have simply used `$UID`

Comment: Yeah I think the argument against (E)UID is that it's not portable - see for example [How to stop a script from running if it's not root (and echo "Not running as root! Exiting...")](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389407/65304)